# How to get hot water

Tags: water-heater

Hot water not working in house that I am remodeling. I’ve never seen this setup before...canceled out water heater with pilot light on?

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: The pictures do not make clear what is connected to what, how, here. You appear to have two water heaters. Either take better pictures or [perhaps the better option for clarity] make a sketch of how & where the pipes run and [edit] your post to include that information. What do you mean by *"canceled out"*?

Comment: why could you not at least post upright pictures? ... it shows a general lack of pride in what you are doing

Comment: Yes, please edit. Show the shut-off valves and pipes connected to each unit.